# gcloud compute ssh from one VM to another VM on Google Cloud

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to ssh into a VM from another VM in Google Cloud using the `gcloud compute ssh` command. It fails with the below message:

```
/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/compute/lib/base_classes.py:9: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  import sets

 Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors for troubleshooting hints.
```

I made sure the ssh keys are in place but still it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12):

There is an assumption that you have connected to the externally-visible instance using SSH beforehand with gcloud.

From your local machine, start ssh-agent with the following command to manage your keys for you:

```
me@local:~$ eval `ssh-agent`
```

Call ssh-add to load the gcloud compute public keys from your local computer into the agent, and use them for all SSH commands for authentication:

```
me@local:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```

Log into an instance with an external IP address while supplying the -A argument to enable authentication agent forwarding.

```
gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-A" INSTANCE
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#sshbetweeninstances.

I am not sure about the 'flags' because it's not working for me bu maybe I have a different OS or Gcloud version and it will work for you.

Comment: On MacOS, I can confirm that the following works: (1) Add `ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`. (2) `gcloud compute --project "<project-name>" ssh --zone "us-west1-a" --ssh-flag="-A" "<node-name>"`

Comment: Thanks, it should be in the google documentation, I was trying to do the same thing and that --ssh-flag="-A" is clearly obscure

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps I ran on my Mac to connect to the Google Dataproc master VM and then hop onto a worker VM from the master MV. I ssh'd to the master VM to get the IP.

`$ gcloud compute ssh cluster-for-cameron-m
Warning: Permanently added '104.197.45.35' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.`

I then `exit`ed. I enabled forwarding for that host.

`$ nano ~/.ssh/config`

`Host 104.197.45.35
ForwardAgent yes`

I added the gcloud key.

`$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`

I then verified that it was added by listing the key fingerprints with `ssh-add -l`. I reconnected to the master VM and ran `ssh-add -l` again to verify that the keys were indeed forwarded. After that, connecting to the worker node worked just fine.

`ssh cluster-for-cameron-w-0`

Answer (score 1):

About using SSH Agent Forwarding...

Because instances are frequently created and destroyed on the cloud, the (recreated) host fingerprint keeps changing. If the new fingerprint doesn't match with `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, SSH automatically disables Agent Forwarding. The solution is:

```
$  ssh -A -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ...
```